# will ECS fargate cost for creating a cluster, without creating any tasks or services

Tags: amazon-ecs

I wanted to know in AWS ECS fargate not EC2, we create fargate cluster and inside that we run the tasks or services.

I have 10 different task definitions all are for specific purposes

I am planning to create 10 clusters and run each task inside them. I want to do this mainly for segragation purpose

Will the above setup charged same as running all the tasks inside one cluster

Will just creating ECS fargate cluster assign any compute resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will just creating ECS fargate cluster assign any compute resources.

No, you will not be charged anything for an ECS Fargate cluster with no running tasks. You only